# How to capture a string containing newlines in regex?

Tags: php, html, regex, string, text

I am trying to capture the strings `Some Text 1`, `Some Text 2`, `Some Text 3` and `Some Text 4` in

```
<div class="main" style="background:red;">
Some Text 1
<div style="color:blue;">Hello 1</div>
Some Text 2
<span style="color:blue;">Hello 2</span>
Some Text 3
<pre style="color:blue;">Hello 3</pre>
Some Text 4
</div>
```

using `/(^[^><].*?[^><]$)/mg` which works fine except when when I add new lines between the tags inside the `main` tag then the tag and its content is also captured. Also when I add newline inside the tags in `main`, before `hello [num]` and after `hello[num]` then `hello [num]` is also captured.

Here is the first case https://regex101.com/r/oT9aA5/2 and this is the second case https://regex101.com/r/oT9aA5/3 also this is a combination of the two cases https://regex101.com/r/oT9aA5/4

Can this be fixed to capture only `Some Text 1`, `Some Text 2`, `Some Text 3` and `Some Text 4`. Basically, I am trying to capture any strings inside a tag that contains other tags.

Comment: Can you go [here](https://regex101.com/r/oT9aA5/1) and show what your input is that breaks, because I've added returns that don't break the regex.

Comment: @ShawnMehan, Here is the first case https://regex101.com/r/oT9aA5/2 and this is the second case https://regex101.com/r/oT9aA5/3 also this is a combination of the two cases https://regex101.com/r/oT9aA5/4

Comment: regex is not made for html parsing. Don't use regex in this case. There can be a lot of use cases for html. It's better to use JQuery or Javascript to get the desired result. Ultimately html is also XML structured text. You can use XML or HTML parsing.

Answer (score -1):

OK, here is a regex that meets your test case:

```
>([\w\s]*)<[^\/]
```

https://regex101.com/r/oT9aA5/8

Your last element bears no contextual difference to `Hello 1`. To capture the last string you should use a new regex and merge the results. It is unclear what the context is for your remaining strings. If it is the last string then you can capture it via

```
 ([\w\s]*)<\/div>$
```

Comment: This captures `Hello 1` too.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to capture any strings inside a tag that contains other tags.